# Text got misaligned after psfrag replacement took place in .eps

Tags: eps, psfrag, baseline

I need to translate to translate texts in eps files. For this i use psfrag package like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\psfrag{valid}[][][0.8]{справжній}
\psfrag{match}[][][0.8]{збіг}
...
\includegraphics{rk-figure.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But after replacement some words are misaligned. Here you can see that word `молодший` is a bit higher than `старший`. Can i use some LaTeX command to avoid this.

[image]

---

Investigation has shown that the porblem comes from how latex aligns original, english, characters. In this example it is `g` in `high-order`.

So, i would like to put `\strut` inside eps file to make all baseline aligned the same. But i can't do like this:

```
1 -99.5 -100 @w
268 1685 :M
(\strut{}high-order)S
```

Is there another option? Maybe there is a known letter which has biggest depth, which i can put in the beginning of each label in eps file?

Comment: Can you update with a minimal working example, MWE. That is a compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. We also need the eps file.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the fifth letter (the one before sha, which I am afraid is the only Cyrillic letter I know). But that is just a wild guess. A quick fix could be to use `\raisebox`.

Comment: @StefanH but this will raise `д` (de)

Comment: You can use a negative raise, like `\raisebox{-3pt}{ABC}`

Comment: @StefanH Thank you, i see, you mean to raise whole word. But i have lots of figures and i could change font in future, i would like to have general solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help without a MWE, but I would recommend putting a `\strut` in all your replacement texts to align text boxes.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean like this `\psfrag{valid}[][][0.8]{\strut{}справжній}`? This doesn't help:( I can add a picture, with strut actually drawn to see it more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, i found the source of the error, the problem is in orignal, english, letters, in this case it was `g` in `high-order`. I will post an answer soon. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `\strut` is a (La)TeX command specifying a distance of height `0.7\baselineskip` and depth `0.3\baselineskip`. Postscript (ps) is a different language and hence does not understand this.

Since strut comes from typesetting I am pretty sure it is possible to make it in ps, but  can't say how. What you could try is to just replace the text with whatever that does not have letters with depth (e.g. g or j). But I doubt this will work since the positioning is already done in the ps file.

for the cases where you have a depth of the letter I would try to find it, starting with `0.3\baselineskip` and raising with this value. If you have the same font in all ps-files you only have to find this value once.